# audio and video msg in SignalR

Tags: c#, signalr

I'm developing a chat application using signalR and I finished the text chat but I'm wondering if signalR support the audio and video messages ?? and if it does what are the best way to implement it i have read the wiki on github i have implemented all the chat appilcation using a simple text chat but i couldn't find any solution of how to work around with audio and video do any one know how can i do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SignalR is for sending out small messages to signal data or changes. Therefore you should transmit a link to the actual image or video in this case. The way the web works ;)